# How Can I Get Perl 5.22 Supported on Travis CI

Tags: perl, travis-ci

The "Ask A Question" link on [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) points to StackOverflow, so …

Perl 5.22 has been in the wild since June. It appears that 5.20 is the latest that Travis supports. What can I do (or who should I pester) to bring Perl 5.22 support to [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/)?

Comment: While the Help dropdown menu on http://travis-ci.org does have an "Ask A Question" link, there is also a documentation link which should perhaps be your first stop.  Within the help sub-site, the menu has a "Contact" section with [Twitter](https://twitter.com/travisci), [GitHub](http://github.com/travis-ci), and [blog](http://blog.travis-ci.com/) links.  The [GitHub issue tracker for `travis-ci`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues) seems to be the primary venue for support requests like yours. See in particular https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4077

Comment: Perfect, @tripleee. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Travis Perl Helpers](http://blogs.perl.org/users/graham_knop/2014/10/travis-ci-perl-helpers.html) which will allow testing on versions of perl not packaged by travis, allow testing against blead, allow building perl with and without threads, and other nifty tricks.

At a minimum, adding the `before_install` stanza for the helpers with the `--perl` option and adding `"5.22"` to your `perl` list should add 5.22 (and any other version) support to an existing recipe.